# Can we import users to Azure AD from sql server user table

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory

We have .net applications and each have its own user tables (some of them AspNetUsers table). Now we think about using Azure Active Directory as a central place to do authentication&authorization. Is there a way to import users to Azure AD from our existing sql server user tables? I don't seem to find such a way, all I see is something like important from local AD.

Comment: What do you want to do with the user passwords? Can they be generated for you, and then changed buy the user?

Comment: yes, we can ask customers to do that. So existing password (They are hashed in the table) cannot be used any more?

Comment: I mean, they could be reused in AAD, but it is unlikely that you can simply copy the hashes over to AAD, nor should you really be able to... If you can get the unhashed versions of the password, my answer below allows you to set the password explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the AAD Graph API or AAD PowerShell you can programmatically create new Users in your Tenant.

For the [AAD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser):

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users

Body:

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Alex Wu",
  "mailNickname": "AlexW",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": true
  },
  "userPrincipalName": "Alex@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

You can find samples to access the AAD Graph API across a number of languages on [GitHub](https://github.com/azure-samples).

For [AAD PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0):

```
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile

$PasswordProfile.Password = "Password"

$PasswordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = $true

New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "New User" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName "NewUser@contoso.com" -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "Newuser"
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done this already, The query results in SQL can be saved to a CSV. Then use PowerShell to import into Azure. The caveat being you would need an AAD account that can do the import portion. Since PowerShell modules for Azure AD are finicky, it seems, you should update your PowerShell by doing the following.

```
PS C:\> Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -RequiredVersion 2.0.2.5 -Verbose -Force
```

Go to this page to get the latest version info. (Downloading from this site did not work for me, however, running the above script did.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.17

Once updated, use the following script to import the file.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -ServicePrincipal
Account: AzureUser@contosso.onmicrosoft.com
Environment: AzureCloud #usually the region your AAD is located, such as CentralUS.
Subscription: yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy
Tenant: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ComplexPasswordString" -AsPlainText -Force
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Path to CSV file\SQL_USER_FILE.csv'
$Users | ForEach-Object { 
New-AzureRmADUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -Password $SecureStringPassword -MailNickname $_.MailNickName -Verbose
 }
```

And if that doesn't work due to login, the more simplified version will work, but will require you to login with your AAD account.

```
Connect-AzureRMAccount
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ComplexPasswordString" -AsPlainText -Force
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Path to CSV file\SQL_USER_FILE.csv'
$Users | ForEach-Object { 
New-AzureRmADUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -Password $SecureStringPassword -MailNickname $_.MailNickName -Verbose
 }
```

*I User -Verbose to give me a running status of the import. Without it, the execution is silent*.  Oh, it took about 15 minutes to do 1500 users on a gigabit connection. Tp give you an idea how long it takes.

The particulars to automating login can be found here. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/connect-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-6.12.0

**Caveat**
The CSV must have the required fields shown above. So you might need to do a little finagling to get them to match. Just know that the only real important field is going to be the -UserPrincipalName = user@contosso.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: Addenda: The thing about this script is it only adds the user. You would need to do another PowerShell Script to assign membership to groups and applications. You might be able to run this with -Password $_."Password". I haven't tested it.